# Study of a Cauchy Problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm in trouble with this problem. The equation is:

> $$y'(x)=\frac{y(x)}{x-1}+x(y(x))^2$$

With the initial condition $y(0)=a$

With "a" a real number.

I have to discuss local existence and uniqueness of solutions and find explicitly the solution, depending on a.

I think that it would be easy to prove local existance of solutions. I really don't know how I have to start to find explicitely the solutions. I've tried by separation of variables with no good results. Could someone give me a hint to start? Thank you very Much :).

Comment: Looks like a Bernoulli Equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Bernouilli's equation

$$y'(x)=\frac{y(x)}{x-1}+x(y(x))^2$$
Divide by $y^2 \ne 0$
$$\frac {y'}{y^2}-\frac 1{y(x-1)}=x$$
Substitute $z=\frac 1 {y}$
$$z'+\frac z {x-1}=-x$$

It's simple to solve now...
$$z'x-z'+z=-x(x-1)$$
$$(zx)'-z'=-x(x-1)$$
Just integrate
$$z(x-1)=-\int x(x-1)dx$$
$$z=-\frac 1 {(x-1)} \int x^2-xdx$$
$$\frac 1 y=-\frac 1 {(x-1)} ( \frac {x^3}3-\frac {x^2}2 +K)$$
$$ y(x)=\frac  {(1-x)} {( \frac {x^3}3-\frac {x^2}2 +K)}$$
$$ \boxed {y(x)=\frac  {6(1-x)} {( {2x^3}- {3x^2} +K)}}$$

I let you finish. find the constante K with the cauchy condition..$y(0)=a$

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast and detailled answer!!
I have a question, just to proof if I have undertood well the point: which are the extremas of the last integral you have wrote? From 0 to a? Thank you very much.

Comment: I added some lines the integral has no bounds. The cauchy condition helps you find the constant K @lorerock92

Comment: Wow, thank you for your reply! Now it's all clear. K it's equal to "6/a". Now I'll find a solution depending on a. Moreover if I want to find the values of "a" that the solution is defined in (- infinity, 1) how i should choose "a"? My idea is to put the denominator different from 0, so I'm expecting to have 3 point of discontinuity. Maybe I have to choose "a" for let these points coming over 1, so the function would be continuous in (- infinity, 1). What do you think of my idea? Thank you so much! :).

Comment: yw @lorerock92 yep $k=\frac 6a$ when a is not nul ...when $a=0$ then $y=0$  ...see what happen to the equation  post your work people will help you and correct it

Comment: Thank you for your reply, you can find my idea on this topic above. I'm pretty new on this platform, so I hope to have done all well! :).

Answer (score 0):

For the domain of $y(x)$ I have to study

$2x^{3}-3x^{2}+\frac{6}{a}=0$ with $a\neq0$.

If $a=0$  , $y(x)=0$ is a solution.

For finding the other discontinuity points I have two idea: one is to try to scompose by Ruffini theorem the polinomia of grade 3 to obtain 3 solutions, the other is considering

$y(x,a)=2x^{3}-3x^{2}+\frac{6}{a}$

and computing the $\nabla{f}(x,a)=0$ to find and eventually classify the discontinuity point.

I want to obtain the values of $a$ such that $y(x)$ is defined on $(-\infty,1)$.

I think that "defined" means that for a certain values of $a$, $y(x)$ mustn't have discontinuity points on $(-\infty,1)$.

Thank you very much!!. .